# In old iPads, symbol '=>' (in (key,value) => ) throws an error

Tags: javascript, ios

Only in old iPads, this code:

`"const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value;"`

generates an error: **"symbol '>' is NOT expected"**.

Is there a workaround for this?

I have "fixed" this problem by not offering the functionality to iOs that requires the above code. This is **not** an acceptable fix. The app should be capable of providing the same services and functionality in all platforms.

Comment: See the [compat tables for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Integrate Babel into your built process to transpile newer syntax down to ES5 automatically. Don't dumb down your code to make it compatible with old browsers, instead *transpile* your code afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions weren't introduced to iOS WebKit until iOS 10, so they are not supported on devices which run an older version. You'll have to use normal function syntax, instead:

```
function replacer(key, value){
    return value === null ? '' : value;
}
```

Comment: Or use babel :)